# How to initialize the data from LocalStorage before ReactDOM.render in a react App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using redux as my state management system and storing my authentication token in LocalStorage. Whenever I am logged in and reload my page it flickers between logged out state and then gets back to the logged-in page.
How can I initialize data from LocalStorage and the do the rendering after data has come?

Comment: Neil, did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

one approach is store in localStorage and then grab straight from state initialisation when your component loads. consider your top level component state, you could do something like this:

`const [user, setUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')))`

this is how I overcame the flicker in my app. if you grab it immediately rather than in `useEffect` or when the component mounts, it should work